# Copying the Generic List

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have 2 generic lists like:

```
public class List1
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim2 { get; set; }
}

public class List2
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim { get; set; }
}
```

I need to copy `list1` items to `list2` one by one.

For example `list1` items are:

```
Tag = 1 
Resim1 = cıvata
Resim2 = somun
Tag = 2 
Resim1 = vida,
Resim2 = tornavida
```

I need to be copy those items to `list2` like

```
Tag = 1
Resim =cıvata
Tag = 1 
Resim = Somun
Tag = 2 
Resim = vida
Tag = 2 
Resim = tornavida
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: To gain clarification, are list1 and list2 objects stored in collections?

Comment: list2 is empty. Lıke as i said i need to copy list1 items to list2

Comment: Txtspk is not likely to get  you any fans on Stackoverflow...

Comment: How are you putting string into `Resim` which is `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to split the Resim1, Resim2 byte[] into a single instance of List2 type, but keeping the associated Tag? If so, this would work:

Setup

```
        var lst1 = new List<List1>
        {
            new List1
            {
                Tag = "1", 
                Resim1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("cıvata"),
                Resim2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("somun")
            },
            new List1
            {
                Tag = "2", 
                Resim1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("vida"),
                Resim2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tornavida")
            },
        };
```

Then:

```
        var list2Collection = new List<List2>();

        foreach (var item in lst1)
        {
            list2Collection.Add(new List2{ Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim1});
            list2Collection.Add(new List2 { Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim2 });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to do, but if you want to populate a collection of List2 objects from an existing collection of List1 objects, here is one way (using Linq):

```
// List<List1> list1Coll = new List<List1>();
// list1Coll.Add( .... )            

List<List2> list2Coll = list1Coll.Select(o => new List2() { Tag = o.Tag, Resim = o.Resim1 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what you're trying to do. I assume you're making two lists, one with your list1 as items, and an empty one with your list2 as items, such as this:

```
        List<List1> list1 = new List<List1>();
        List<List2> list2 = new List<List2>();
```

This is confusing, as your list class isn't a list, it's an item. Nevertheless, there are many ways to add your first list's items to your second list, simplest would just be to add them iteratively, such as this:

```
foreach (List1 item in list1)
        {
            if (item.Resim1 != null)
                list2.Add(new List2() { Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim1 });
            if (item.Resim2 != null)
                list2.Add(new List2() { Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim2 });
        }
```

Keep in mind that your Tag won't be your index, and you would have to convert the example values you provided from string to byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Correct your concept of generic list first

Do the following

```
public class YourClassName1
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim2 { get; set; }
} 

public class YourClassName2
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public byte[] Resim { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get your new generic lists as

```
var list1 = new List<YourClassName1>();
var list2 = new List<YourClassName2>();
```

Now mix up data after input as

```
foreach(var item in list1)
{
  list2.Add(new YourClassName2{Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim1});
  list2.Add(new YourClassName2{Tag = item.Tag, Resim = item.Resim2});
}
```